# How to create gin.Context from *http.Request and *httptest.ResponseRecorder?

Tags: go, testing, go-gin

I would like to create a test helper for [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/) similar to [testify's HTTPBodyContain](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#HTTPBodyContains).

I am having a hard time creating `gin.Context` from `*http.Request` and `*httptest.ResponseRecorder`. I've already written something like this:

```
func HTTPBodyContains(t *testing.T, handler gin.HandlerFunc, method, url string, values url.Values, str interface{}, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool {
    body := HTTPBody(handler, method, url, values)

    contains := strings.Contains(body, fmt.Sprint(str))
    if !contains {
        assert.Fail(t, fmt.Sprintf("Expected response body for \"%s\" to contain \"%s\" but found \"%s\"", url+"?"+values.Encode(), str, body))
    }

    return contains
}

func HTTPBody(handler gin.HandlerFunc, method, url string, values url.Values) string {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url+"?"+values.Encode(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    handler(&gin.Context{
        Request: req,
        Writer:  gin.ResponseWriter(w),
    })
    return w.Body.String()
}
```

but this wouldn't work

```
Writer:  gin.ResponseWriter(w)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it seems there is [CreateTestContext](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#CreateTestContext) that does what I was looking for.

```
func CreateTestContext(w http.ResponseWriter) (c *Context, r *Engine)
```

> CreateTestContext returns a fresh engine and context for testing purposes